# Prove that given a number we can find whether there're 2 elements in a red/black tree that their sum equals that number in $\Theta(n)$ time

Tags: algorithms, trees, balanced-search-trees

> Prove that given a number we can find whether there're 2 elements in a red/black tree that their sum equals that number in $\Theta(n)$ time and **constant** space.

The original problem appears [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-pair-with-given-sum-in-bst/),
however the solution uses $\lg n$ space.
A problem in my course required adjusting the algorithm such that we use constant space.

I thought of the following algorithm:

```
MyAlgorithm(root, num)
    min<-findMin(root)
    max<-findMax(root)
    while(min.key <= max.key && min != max)
        if((min.key + max.key)=num) return true
        if((min.key + max.key) < num)
            min<-successor(min)
        else
            max<-predeccessor(max)
    return false
```

According the CLRS book both `predeccessor()` and `successor()` functions time complexity depends on tree height which is $O(\lg n)$ in our case since red-black tree is balanced.

However, we have the `while` loop which theoretically can run almost `n` times.

For example, because the algorithm above is equivalent to searching for the number `num` in a sorted array, say we have this array and `num<-3`:
$$
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
$$
In this case we'll call `predecessor(max)` $8$ times which is almost $\Theta(n)$ or $\Theta((n-2)\lg n)=\Theta(n\lg n)$ asymptotically.

Am I wrong in my conclusions? How can I prove that the time complexity is indeed $\Theta(n)$?

Comment: 1.  Please credit the original source of the problem.  2. Do you allow modifying the tree?  3. If only we had a way to do in-order traversal in constant space, we could apply https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13585/755.  Hmm.  It's just possible it might be worth your time to try searching on that topic.

Comment: @D.W. we cannot modify the tree. The post https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13585/how-to-develop-an-on-algorithm-solve-the-2-sum-problem doesn't nearly have the restrictions that I have in the post, I don't really see the connection.

Comment: Can you clarify *precisely* what constant space means?  Do you mean a constant number of memory cells, where each memory cell can hold a $\lg n$-bit number or a pointer into the tree?  Do you mean a constant number of bits of memory?  The former is probably the natural meaning.  The latter is unlikely to be what you mean -- that isn't even enough to store a pointer to a single node in the tree.  If the former, then you have $O(\lg n)$ bits -- can you think of any way to do an in-order traversal, if you were able to store $O(\lg n)$ bits?

Comment: @D.W.  such details were not mentioned in the original problem, all that was said was "constant space".

Comment: You said you saw the "original problem" somewhere else.  Where?  Was it in a book?  A course?  A programming contest?  I encourage you to edit the question to tell us where you encountered the problem and provide credit to the place where you originally saw the problem.  I'm not sure what post you are referring to.  I'm talking about the statement of the problem, not your algorithm, not your code.

Comment: What makes you think it can be solved in constant space?  You said that the original problem said constant space, but the [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-pair-with-given-sum-in-bst/) you provided in the question doesn't say anything about constant space.

Comment: A problem in my course required adjusting the algorithm such that we use constant space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we are given a binary search tree $T$ (we, however, do not require it to be balanced). Also we are given an integer; let's call it `target_number`. We wish to query whether there are two distinct nodes in $T$ such that the sum of their values equals `target_number`. In order to do that, we need two functions: `get_successor(x)` and `get_predecessor(x)`. Given a node `x` `get_successor(x)` returns the tree node whose value is larger than that of `x` and is the smallest such value. The definition of `get_predecessor(x)` is symmetric.

The algorithm is now (as in your question): point to the minimum node, and point to the maximum node. Compute the sum $S$ of the nodes pointed by the two pointers. If $S$ is less than the target number, move left pointer to its successor node. If $S$ is greater than the target number, move right pointer to its predecessor node. Otherwise, we have a match and return `true`.

```
query(root, target_number)
    left_finger  = the minimum node of the entire tree rooted at root
    right_finger = the maximum node of the entire tree rooted at root

    while left_finger != nil and right_finger != nil and left_finger != right_finger
        tentative_sum = left_finger.value + right_finger.value
        if tentative_sum < target_number
            left_finger = get_successor(left_finger)
        else if tentative_sum > target_number
            right_finger = get_predecessor(right_finger)
        else
            return true
    return false
```

Next, we need to give a strong argument that it runs, in fact, in $\Theta(n)$. Take a look at operation `get_successor`: If you start from the minimum node and visit the entire tree in successor order, you do $\Theta(n)$ work regardless the fact that `get_successor` runs in worst case $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$, and that is why: you visit each node at most three times: from the parent, returning from the left child and returning from the right child; we spend constant time at each node.

As you can see from the below diagram, each node `x` has at most 3 incoming arcs and has at most 3 outgoing arcs. Traversing each arc is $\Theta(1)$. So basically, if we start from a minimum node, and keep advancing to the successor nodes, we do essentially in-order traversal that is, however, iterative instead of recursive. Same argument for starting from the maximum node via `get_predecessor`.

Now, we do the same traversal but in "both directions" (the `left_finger` proceeds towards successor nodes and `right_finger` proceeds towards predecessor nodes, and we terminate (at latest) when the two fingers meet. Thus, running time is linear in tree size and space complexity constant since no recursion is involved.

[image: In-order traversal and successor traversal]

Comment: @coderodde, I have doubts that I hope you can help me with. First, this seems like it would rely on being able to access the node's parent, which you could argue is possible in a RB tree. Then you mention this works for any tree, but it seems impossible to work with a tree that has no node reference to it's parent. Without a reference to the parent we can't keep track of parents in constant space without modifying the tree. This means `getSuccessor` can make the total time at least $n \log n$.

Comment: @ryan "works for any tree" - I meant that the algorithm works for trees of any ***topology*** (not necessarily balanced trees). As far I understand, RB-tree has to fix itself by starting at a node and going upwards towards root, which -- ultimately -- requires a parent fields in each node. I am confident that you can solve the problem even on trees whose nodes has no parent field, but that might be less efficient than $\Theta(n)$.

Answer (score -1):

First thing that popped into my mind, was using a hashmap (or just a key - storage) while iterating.

In the HashTable, I would store an addend for the sum, and while iterating I would look up if the value is in the list.

```
Addends[] //KeySet
for value in Values {
   if(Addends.contains(value) // Pair found
     return true
   Addends.add(Sum - value)
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but it is not $\Theta(n)$ but $\mathcal O(n^2)$.

Comment: It's not. I am iterating only once and the KeySet lookup requires only O(1)

Comment: This is expected lookup time, also the average case is constant, but the worst case for the hash lookup is $\mathcal O(n)$, so it is not tight bound. If the KeySet has a tree underneath then it is $\mathcal O(log n)$ per lookup.

Comment: Okay, but in this case, the KeySet is a HashTable with a constant lookup. You could be having collision, yes, you could avoid them, by looking them up. You are just looking for Key Values. So it won't matter.

Comment: HashTable doesn't provide constant lookup, besides with additional table the constant space requirement is not met.

Comment: Of course it is constant, what else? Average is O(1) and worst case O(n), but in this case the worst case might never happen, because you might not care of collision, because they won't matter.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Look at method 2, exactly my suggested implementation http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/

Comment: They will matter because the calculated hash gives you the key - index in the array. If it collides it will yield false positive results. You are right, the wirst case will occur very rarely, but as far as it may occur, this breaks given constraints. Also you will need at least $n$ bins, but one of the requirements is **constant memory**. Thank you for the link, but I am aware how hashes work and read it already. It is called *expected* $\mathcal O(1)$. BTW -1 is not mine. If you know that the worst case is O(n) then you should know that it is $\mathcal O(n^2)$ by now.

Comment: Auxiliary space is $\mathcal O(R)$, but $R$ may be arbitrary large, orders of magnitude greater than $n$. I agree that your solution is nice but under different constraints than given. Both time and space exceeds constraints.