# Is it possible to solve 3SUM in $O(n^2)$ time?

Tags: complexity-theory, lower-bounds

**Problem:** **3SUM**

**Input:** Three lists A, B and C of integers and an integer k. Each list contain $n$ numbers.
**Task:** Decide whether there exists a tuple (a, b, c) ∈ A × B × C such that a + b + c = k.

**Question :** Is it possible to solve **3SUM** in $O(n^2)$ time using constant space ? Prove or disprove it

Answer (score 5):

A $O(n^2)$ algorithm (with $O(1)$ space) is as follows:

- Sort $A$, $B$, and $C$ individually in $O(n \log n)$.
- For each $a \in A$:

  - Search a pair of $b \in B$ and $c \in C$ such that $b + c = k - a$. This can be done in $O(n)$ by traversing $B$ from the smallest to the largest and $C$ from the largest to the smallest. (Tip: Comparing $b + c$ with $k-a$ each time.)

Answer (score 2):

<del>This question is not a 3sum problem.</del> The question can be solved with hash tables. For each element in **C** traverse **A** and see if the corresponding element exists in **B**. Time complexity would be $O(|C|*|A|*1) = O(|C||A|)$

Edit:
Answer to the updated question:

This problem can be treated as **2SUM** problem for each element in **C** (or any other list as they are symmetrical). That is for each $c \in C$ we find solutions for the sum $k - c$ using elements from **A** and **B**.

For a $O(1)$ auxiliary space algorithm one can first sort **A** and **B**. Then use 2-pointer algorithm ([Tutorial](https://tp-iiita.quora.com/The-Two-Pointer-Algorithm)) to solve the 2SUM problem in $O(n)$.

Comment if you have doubts on implementation. You can also see https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13586/81272

Comment: What about space complexity ?

Comment: are you sure? This seems to be 3sum problem.