# Is the following Subset Sum variant NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, np-hard, decision-problem

Is the following problem NP-hard:

**Input:** $A\subset\mathbb Z, k\in\mathbb N$
**Question:** is there a *multiset of indices* $I$, such that $|I|=k$ and $\sum_{i\in I} a_i=0$?

For example, on the input $A=\{-1,2\}, k=3$ we can take $I=\{1,1,2\}$ and thus we get $|I|=3$ and $a_1+a_1+a_2=(-1)+(-1)+2=0$, as desired.

Comment: I know that there's an easy reduction from Subset Sum problem to inputs of the form $A,k$ where $I$ should be a set. Also, I know that there's an easy reduction from this problem to Subset Sum problem by taking $A$ to be a multiset (each element of $A$ should appear $k$ times in the output of the reduction). But I am stuck showing the required reduction.

Comment: I think that careful analysis of the standard reduction from Vertex Cover to Subset Sum will show that you can actually use a multiset, and it wouldn't matter. But I didn't check the details, and it seems like an inelegant solution anyway.

Comment: I can't make edits < 6 characters, but I believe $I = \{1, 1, 2\}$ should be $I = \{-1, -1, 2\}$.

Comment: @orlp, why are you thinking that?  Each element of $I$ is supposed to be an index, so in the example it must be either 1 or 2 (as $|A|=2$, i.e., $a_1=-1$, $a_2=2$).

Comment: @D.W. Ah I missed that they are multisets of _indices_. That's a bit of an indirect way of going about it.

Comment: @D.W. It appears I have misread the paper in my answer. Their algorithm indeed only finds arbitrary integer solutions, and non-negative solutions require some form of post-processing (like integer programming). I'll keep looking.

Comment: Have you tried looking to see if set-partition might reduce to this? The idea of having elements balance out so their sum = 0 got me thinking about that.

Comment: I believe that it is not NP-Hard. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem

Comment: @nick.schachter, why does that suggest the problem is not NP-hard?  If we were limited to $k=3$, then the results about 3-sum would suggest that the problem is not NP-hard.   But in this question $k$ is not limited to $k=3$; $k$ can be arbitrarily large, and thus those methods don't yield a polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: If 0 is present in $A$, then the "exactly $k$" constraint is effectively weakened to "at most $k$", since we can then "pad" a solution with as many copies of 0 as we like. And if we set $k$ "high enough" then we are asking whether there is *any* integer vector $\mathbf x$ such that $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf x=0$, where $\mathbf a$ is a vector representation of $A$ and $\cdot$ is the usual dot product. Pretty sure this problem is NP-hard; the other question is whether it's possible to pick a high enough $k$ that still has size polynomial in the input size (maybe the product of all elements?).

Comment: If 0 is present in $A$, the answer is trivially _yes_ if I correctly understood the problem. (However, the case "at most k" may still be interesting to study).

Answer (score 2):

It is NP-hard.

Consider the following two variants:

**Variant 1:**

**Input:** $A\subset\mathbb N$, $s\in\mathbb N$.
**Question:** is there a **set** of indices $I$, $\sum_{i\in I} a_i=s$?

**Variant 2:**

**Input:** $A\subset\mathbb N$, $k\in\mathbb N$, $s\in\mathbb N$.
**Question:** is there a **multiset** of indices $I$, such that $|I|=k$ and $\sum_{i\in I} a_i=s$?

It is easy to see variant 1 is NP-hard. It is also easy to reduce variant 2 to your variant in polynomial time by transforming each element $e$ in an instance of variant 2 to $ke-s$. So if we can prove there is a polynomial-time reduction from variant 1 to variant 2, the proof is completed.

The reduction from variant 1 to variant 2 is exactly the same as the one posted by Kristoffer Arnsfelt Hansen in [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1002). I rewrite it here for consistency of symbols.

Given an instance of variant 1, assume that $a_i < B$ for all $i$. We will have two new elements for each old element, simulating whether the element is used 0 or 1 times. For element $a_i$ we get two new elements $a^1_i = (2^{n+1} + 2^i)nB + a_i$ and $a^0_i = (2^{n+1} + 2^i)nB$. The new target sum is defined as $s' = (n2^{n+1} + 2^n + \dots + 2^1)nB + s$. The number of elements required in a solution is set to be $n$.

Note in a valid solution of the new instance, for each $i$, the number of $a_i^1$ and that of $a_i^0$ must be exactly $1$ in total, so there is exactly $n$ elements in a valid solution. This is indeed a polynomial-time reduction from variant 1 to variant 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the algorithm for your problem returns the yes/no answer together with the actual multi-set $I$ itself, then we can build a reduction from sub-set sum to your problem by sending your algorithm several $k$'s starting with $k=N,(|A|=N)$ down to $k=2$, where each time we check for repetitiveness to make sure we have a valid minimum sub-set sum. That would be running your algorithm $N-1$ times each time checking validity which sums up to $N(N-1)$ times your algorithm's running time. Conclusion, your problem is NP-Hard.

Note: Even if your algorithm does not return the actual sub multi-set it can be obtained by repeatedly removing one of the set's elements and checking that the sub multi-set still exists.

Comment: How do you handle repetitiveness? Could you please explain more?