# Complexity for optimized k-sum problem

Tags: complexity-theory, combinatorics

Following up on these two posts
[Generalised 3SUM (k-SUM) problem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem/2995#2995?newreg=020d74235a7146778f2f4679e304f7c0)
https://people.csail.mit.edu/virgi/6.s078/lecture9.pdf

The claim is that k-sum in the general case can be solved in $O(n^{k/2}log(n))$

However, I don't follow this claim. The quote reads

> For even : Compute a sorted list  of all sums of /2 input elements. Check whether  contains both some number  and its negation −. The algorithm runs in (/2log) time.

Compute a list of all sums of k/2 input elements. $O(n^{k/2})$

Sort this list: $O(n^{k/2}log(n^{k/2})=O(k/2*n^{k/2}log(n))$

Sandwich with two pointers to find s and -s. We have a valid answer iff the indices of elements that make up s and -s are nonoverlapping. However, because we have to check each instance of -s in order to validate whether the indices are non-overlapping, we end up having a computation that is $O(n^{k/2})$. This means that this step is $O(n^{k/2} * n^{k/2})$.

Am I misunderstanding an optimization?

Comment: Depending on the definition they are using the indices don't have to be distinct.

Comment: Yes but say we desire distinct indices, which is the case for the general statement of the k-sum problem

Comment: If you are fine with a randomized algorithm then you can randomly partition the input collection into two sets $A$ and $B$ and consider the variant in which you need to choose $k/2$ elements from each set. If there is a solution to the original instance, then there is a probability of at least $\frac{\binom{k}{k/2}}{2^k}$ that this solution is evenly split between $A$ and $B$ (I'm assuming that $k$ is even for simplicity) which, using Stirling's approximations and dropping constants, is roughly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$. Repeat $\sqrt{k}\log\frac{1}{p}$ times for a failure probability of about $p$.

Answer (score 0):

In case we desire that all indices are distinct one can use balanced BSTs such as an AVL-Tree to check if indices overlap. For each of the $O(n^{k/2})$ sums you also store the set of indices (using a balanced BST as Data structure). Now creating all these sets takes $O(n^{k/2}k/2\log(k/2))$, because we need to insert $k/2$ elements in every set. Now when check if there exists $-n$ for any $n$ we need to check if their sets overlap. This again takes $O(k/2\log(k/2))$ or for every number $O(n^{k/2}k/2\log(k/2))$.
Thus for constant $k$ we still maintain the runtime $O(n^{k/2}\log(n))$

Comment: Using a BST means that checking the intersection of two sums will take $O(k/2 log(k/2))$. However, if you store indices in sets, you can accomplish this in $O(k/2)$. The core problem is still that because it takes $O(n^{k/2}k/2)$ to check every number, and there are $O(n^{k/2})$ numbers, your run time becomes $O(n^k*k/2)$

Comment: @JasonKang I don't understand - finding a $-n$ for given $n$ only takes log-time since we have sorted the numbers? So for every number we do a binary search to find a matching negative number and then check if indice sets overlap. Where does your runtime come from?

Comment: There can be multiple numbers of the same sum. Given the numbers [1234] the array of k/2 (in this case 2) sums includes 5 twice (once from 1,4 and 2,3). Although you can bound the number of duplicates that occur from k/2 sums, it will likely be on the order of O(k). Checking each duplicate is expensive in k

Comment: To add to that, just considering $\{0,1,2,...,m\}$ there are $O(m/2)$ ways to get $m$ as a 2-sum. So the duplicates are probably polynomial in $m$ for $k$-sums. I don't know how to resolve this.